# How to add a uneditable url in a popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript for opening a new window when clicked on the link.
I want that the new window should dispaly the address bar but the value of that bar should not change.

Can i do that?

the script code  i am usng is:

```
="Javascript:void(window.open('help.aspx?ID=" + Fields!ID.Value +"','mywindow','_self','width=500,height=500'))"
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be what happens using your code already.

Just remove the `__self` argument, it doesn't belong there and overrides your width and height settings.

```
window.open('help.aspx?ID=" + Fields!ID.Value +"','mywindow','width=500,height=500'))"
```

Comment: it does not display the address bar...and it if i set location=1,it displays the address bar but if u want to edit it..it is easily done.

Comment: @jasmeet which browser are you using?

Comment: @jasmeet I don't think there is a way to *force* the browser to display a read-only address bar, but if you turn of all bars, modern Firefoxes and IEs will automatically show one for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below Code:

```
function OpenNonEditableWindow(){
  window.open(
    'YourURL',
    'AnyNameForNewWindow', 
    'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350'
  );
}
```

And Call It Like This :

```
<button type='button' onclick='OpenNonEditableWindow()'>Click Me</button>
```